# Twig - accessing node properties

Tags: theming, 8

How can I access node property which name starts with # in twig template?

I have content type with field Category and I need to access value of that field inside of twig template?

Using dump(content.field_category[0]) I get this

```
array (size=5)
  '#type' => string 'link' (length=4)
  '#title' => string 'Example' (length=5)
```

How to access #title ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line, `{{ content.field_category[0]['#title'] }}` to get  value of title inside twig.

Comment: You don't need the filter `| raw` to get a plain text like a title and it's also a bad example, because if the variable would contain unsafe data you don't want to have it unescaped in the template.

Comment: It is for getting raw value as i said in answer. No need to provide raw if it only plain text

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but raw is unsafe and should not be applied to variables with user input, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates

Comment: Thanks for the information as i did not knew that.